# How to read data from USB OTG Pen Drive in Flutter

Tags: flutter, usb, usb-otg

I face following error :-
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(UsbSerialPortAdapter, Not an Serial device., null, null)

Comment: We are missing crucial details. Which package are you using? Which command causes this exception? Try to reinstall your app on the device

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using usb_serial, it's keen to note that the package does does not support all adapters. A few things I would check.

1. Check your slave device Vendor and Product ID and add them to src/main/res/xml/device_filter.xml . An example `<usb-device vendor-id="4292" product-id="60000" />`
2. Call `UsbSerialDevice.isSupported(device)` and log the results. If it returns `false` you then your device is not supported. Refer to this [#issue24](https://github.com/altera2015/usbserial/issues/24)